# HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime - .NET 6.0

Tags: .net-6.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I have upgraded my project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6. After upgrading I am getting warning like

> warning NETSDK1179: One of '--self-contained' or '--no-self -contained' options are required when '--runtime' is used

I don't want to deploy my code with this warning. I have added

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win81-x64;win7-x64;win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

in every `.csproj` and added

```
--self-contained true
```

to my `dotnet publish` command. But I am still getting those warnings.

I have installed the .NET 6 hosting bundle on my server. It helped to resolve my problem. But I can't install all the environment due to permission issue. If I deploy my code with the warning I am getting error.

Please help me resolve this warning

Comment: If you want to **run** your .NET 6 app on an environment, you **must install** the needed .NET 6 runtime .... - or you create a "self-contained" executable, that includes all the .NET 6 runtime modules in the app; it will be a much larger size, but you won't need to separately install any .NET 6 runtime components - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/